# Reading JSON from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I am having a SQL Query with multiple child FOR JSON Path with a final FOR JSON Path at the end. The JSON being formed is relatively large.
However when I am trying to read the JSON from C# the JSON is not appearing properly. C# code below to read the JSON from SQL Server

```
   var queryWithForJson = "EXEC TEST_SP";
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        conn.Open();
        var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            jsonResult.Append("[]");
        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }
        reader.Close();


        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\file.json");
        file.WriteLine(jsonResult.ToString());
```

The JSON file created is ending with:

```
"Det":[{"id":3700159,"address":"601   Union St  Seattle, WA 98
```

As you can see the JSON did not end properly.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your while loop to debug what is going into your jsonResult?

Comment: How do you want the json look like? What is the expected output? Can you share some data from the sql server too?

Comment: Actually, I think it's file.WriteLine() that's getting you. There is probably a hard return in that string.

Comment: Surely you mean `File.WriteAllText()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `using` statement on your file. I replicated your issue when I didn't do this.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\file.json"))
{
    file.Write(jsonResult.ToString());
}
```

After looking into this a bit more, it looks like you would also get the correct results if you flushed the StreamWriter. You could do that with `file.AutoFlush = true;` or with `file.Flush();`. However you choose to accomplish this, you really should have a using statement around your StreamWriter anyway to be sure it is disposed of correctly.

Comment: I wonder if the using causes a final flush to disk of the StreamWriter....

Comment: I figure it has to be something like that, but I just don't know for sure, so I didn't want to put it in my answer unless someone confirms.

Comment: I checked with the using block and it seems to be working. I will test with a larger result set and updated on the results.